# I'm encountering a 405 Error when I try to upload a post on my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a problem trying to upload a post on my development blog. I'm trying to upload a Post by using the MVC framework. I'm trying to follow a broad number of guides as to how to build a blog.

Here's the Post class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectWebApp.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here's the BlogDBContext:

```
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectBlogWebApp.Data
{
    public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogDbContext(DbContextOptions<BlogDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            if (Database.EnsureCreated() == true)
            {
                Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>().HasKey(p => new {p.PostID, p.TagID});
            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>().HasOne(pt => pt.Post).WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>().HasOne(pt => pt.Tag).WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagID);
        }



        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the PostController class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjectWebApp.Data;
using ProjectWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ProjectWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class PostController : Controller
    {
        private BlogDbContext _dbBlogContext;

        public PostController(BlogDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbBlogContext = dbContext;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var postList = _dbBlogContext.Posts.ToList();

            return View(postList);
        }
        [HttpGet, Route("Create")]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new Post());
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Edit")]
        public IActionResult Edit()
        {
            
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePostAsync([Bind("Title", "Content")] Post post)
        {
            try 
            {
                post.Likes = 0;
                post.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                post.Author = "Leonard Morrison";
                _dbBlogContext.Add(post);
                await _dbBlogContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                
            }

            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.TryAddModelError( "Error: Post was not added properly!", "Sorry, the Post was not added properly. Please let me know if this problem persists");
            }

            return View(post);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Show(int ID)
        {
            var post = getPost(ID);
            return View(post);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int ID)
        {
            var post = getPost(ID);
            return View(post);
        }
        [HttpPatch]
        public IActionResult Update(int id)
        {
            var post = _dbBlogContext.Posts.Find(id);
            _dbBlogContext.Posts.Update(post);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult RemovePost(int id)
        {
            Post deletedPost = getPost(id);

            _dbBlogContext.Posts.Remove(deletedPost);

            _dbBlogContext.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        public Post getPost(int ID)
        {
            var post = _dbBlogContext.Posts.First(p => p.PostID == ID);

            return post;
        }

    }
}
```

and lastly, here's the Startup source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjectWebApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


namespace ProjectBlogWebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {



        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();


            services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<BlogDbContext, BlogDbContext>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //The Main EndPoint Routes
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id}");
            });
            
            //The Post Endpoints Routes
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "post",
                    pattern: "{controller=Post}/{action=Index}/{title?}");

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't know where exactly the error is. But I need to where this 405 Error is coming from.

Thanks.

Comment: And the URL used to make the failing request is..? 405 usually indicates an incorrect URL used or misconfigured route (eg. missing verb). Note that _none_ of the EF stuff is even relevant (nor is significant other portions). Work in creating a _minimal example / reproduction case_.

Comment: Also, *ensure CORS is enabled*, if relevant.

Comment: The URL is "https://localhost:5001/Create". I keep getting a 405 error every time I try to post. I'll get to work on enabling CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

The generate Url is `"localhost:5001/Create"`, which only match the Create Get method, while the form send a HttpPost Request, so it occurs 405 error.

1.You may add a `asp-action="CreatePost"` on your form tag,

2.Or just add a same Route Attribute on your CreatePost action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePostAsync([Bind("Title", "Content")] Post post)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Create View (Create.cshtml) to ensure asp-action="CreatePostAsync" in your form tag.

If that's not the problem, please include your View code as well.

Also put a breakpoint at CreatePostAsync and follow along to see where the error occurs. It's possible the action isn't being triggered. Which means, your breakpoint won't be triggered either.

Few other things that may help either with the problem and/or project:

- BlogDbContext: OnModelCreating(), those codes are to indicate foreignkeys? The ForeignKeys will be automatically created/mapped by EF as long as the property name is {TableName}Id. You can also be explicit by using [ForeignKey] attribute to the ForeignKey
- Controller: You can combine Method and Route [HttpGet("Create")]. I'm certain this isn't the problem but just wanted to let you know
- Create(): Don't need to pass new Post model to view() since your view will already have "@model Post"
- CreatePostAsync(): I'd suggest creating a PostViewModel with the necessary properties and the validation checks. Use the PostViewModel as the parameter. This also means you'll need to update your Create view from @model Post to @model PostViewModel
- CreatePostAsync(): Always redirect a post method back to get after it's done processing. Only time you should return View() would be if there are errors. Otherwise, a user can spam refresh and create multiple lines of data. Try it for yourself actually once you get the Create working